# Proxying all requests for a Windows Server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, proxy

Is it possible to proxy out all requests from a Windows server? We have a proxy set up but for each situation I need to configure that application to use a proxy. For example, I can set the proxy settings in IE, but not everything respects that. I have chef-client installed on these Windows servers, chef-client will respect its own proxy setting I put in the client.rb but when it calls on webpi to install something off the internet, that does not respect the proxy setting.

Simply, is there anyway in Windows (or maybe a third party app) to send all requests to a proxy server?

Comment: Plug the Windows server's NIC(s) into the proxy server, so everything has to go through the proxy server.

Comment: It's a per-user setting. Plus, the local system is a user. And so are any service accounts. So it's not something that can really be done globally with one method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Netsh.exe winhttp set proxy proxy:port

Example
Netsh.exe winhttp set proxy squid.domain.com:3128